# Why are my Erlang indent settings different on MacVim vs. gVim?

Tags: vim

I'm using the [same `.vimrc` and `.vim` folder](https://github.com/rlipscombe/vimrc) on my Mac (MacVim) and on my Linux box (gVim). As far as I can tell, this means that my vim configuration should be more-or-less identical on both.

However, when I use <kbd>gg=G</kbd> to indent an Erlang source file (in particular), the Mac uses 10-character indents for record declarations, and the Linux box uses 8-character indents for the same.

Why are they different?

What settings should I change to make them the same?

Answer (score 0):

Vim has all of its default filetype plugins, etc. in the vimruntime folder.

You might be able make them behave the same by copying the syntax files you prefer to the proper place under ~/.vim/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Ubuntu includes gVim 7.3 by default, and MacVim is 7.4. Combined with this snippet in https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl/blob/master/indent/erlang.vim#L11:

```
if exists('b:did_indent') || (v:version >= 704 && ...
    finish
```

...it means that gVim and MacVim use completely different indent scripts for Erlang.

Given that one is written in vim script, and the other in Erlang, I didn't want to waste time getting them to behave the same.

So I upgraded gVim on Ubuntu to 7.4 by using a PPA. Now they're the same.